# Possible to interpolate predefined functions to Live Template in IntelliJ IDEA family IDEs?

Tags: intellij-idea

### Task

Using IntelliJ IDEA **Live templates**, generate below template where "something" is dynamic part:

```
private _somethingInBeingSubmittedNow: boolean = false;
private _somethingSubmittingError: boolean = false;

@Action
public async submitSomething(): Promise<void> {

}
```

In `_$TARGET$InBeingSubmittedNow` and `_$TARGET$SubmittingError`, word or phrase must begin with small letter, however in `submit$TARGET$()` **same** word or phrase must begin with capital letter. User must input desired word or phrase only one time.

### What we have AFAIK

[Predefined Functions to Use in Live Template Variables](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/edit-template-variables-dialog.html#predefined_functions) works in "edit variables" dialog, but here it's no use. We need to interpolate pre-defined functions to reach desired effect.

[image]

### Invalid solution

[image]

```js
private _$TARGET$InBeingSubmittedNow: boolean = false;
private _$TARGET$SubmittingError: boolean = false;

@Action
public async submit$capitalize($TARGET$)$(): Promise<void> {

}
```

The `$capitalize($TARGET$)$` is invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set second variable (e.g. TARGET_CAPITALIZED) and use "capitalize(TARGET)" as an expression in "Edit Variables"

Comment: It is the solution! Thank you for the answer!